# Connect from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 15.04 using Windows Remote Desktop?

Tags: 15.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I have looked for this issue on this forum, but most of the information seems to be at least 2-3 years outdated. Hence I made a new post.

I currently have a VPS running Ubuntu 15.04 (64bit) and I connect to it using TightVNC. It works fine, but the delay in using the VNC client is quite noticeable and the quality of the image isn't as clear. So I was looking in to using Windows Remote Desktop, seeing as I have connected to other Windows computers using it, and boy is it fluent and fast!

I have read a lot of articles on the XRDP stuff but, like I said, most of the stuff is out-dated.

So, I would like to ask this question again, in 2015.

Can I connect to Ubuntu 15.04 using Windows Remote Desktop? If so, how do I go about setting it up? OR are there other options that perform just as good or better than Windows Remote Desktop?

I hope to hear from you.

Cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but this page seems to document setting up rdp on Linux for connections from windows remote desktop client:

http://www.technig.com/remote-access-windows-10-via-ubuntu-vise-versa/

Essentially:

1. `sudo apt-get install xrdp`
2. set up a session (example: `echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession`)
3. start the session and keep it running

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question, but have decided to use splashtop for this purpose. It only works with Ubuntu 14.04 for now though.

http://www.splashtop.com/downloads#pers_sec

Perhaps it's an improvement to TigerVNC?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use TeamViewer. It is really simple to setup. All you need to do is create an account and add your Linux machine to it, and then allow unattended access. Then you can use TeamViewer on any other Windows machine and login and remote Desktop your Linux machine. TeamViewer also has an app for iOS and Android.